# How do I change the monitor resolution in xubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xubuntu, xorg, resolution

I am using xUbuntu 14.04.1 LTS and I'm having a problem where the OS is using a resolution of 1280x1024@77Hz, but my monitor (a Dell 2209WA) has a native resolution of 1680x1050@60Hz resulting in a stretched appearance.

For reference, I am using the Nouveau display driver and I have an NVIDIA Geforce GTX 760 rev a1 video card. My kernel is 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP. I have no xorg.conf file.

my Xorg.0.log is available at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iC9YGpxf)

What do I need to do to get Ubuntu to use the correct resolution and aspect ratio for my monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old VGA cable with DVI-to-VGA converters on either end to connect the video card to the monitor. At the suggestion of a colleague, I swapped that kludge out for a single link DVI-D cable and after a restart Ubuntu was able to automatically detect the correct resolution and aspect ratio for my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try System settings -> Displays [image: Displays dialog in Xubuntu]

Comment: The only resolution available in the drop down is 1280x1024.